# How to create csv file and save to file filed in django model?

Tags: python, django, export-to-csv

I'm using django csv (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/outputting-csv/) and i want to save generated csv file to file field in below model

```
class CsvDoc(models.Model):
    csv_file = models.FileField(
    upload_to="path")
```

Answer (score 0):

For save this file you need to write down one function in views.py and then save the file. Code is below:

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('file.html', {'form': form})
```

where UploadForm is a form class and you need to write down that in forms.py file:

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = CsvDoc
```

And in file.html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/file/" name="test" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<input id="formSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Try this, and tell me that it is works fine or not. Thanks.